# PHP - List free time slots in a planning day

Tags: php, time

I have a day planning that displays meetings. Each meeting has a `start` and `end` values. (In `time format 00:00`) and they are all between `08:30` and `17:00` and my meetings length are always a multiple of `15 min` (00:15,00:30,00:45,1:00 etc...)

I'm trying to define a launch break of `1 hour` that isn't inside any meeting.
In other words, i'm trying to list the free time slots.

My meetings are in a object :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meetings] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start] => 8:30
                    [end] => 12:00
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [start] => 14:00
                    [end] => 16:00
                )

        )

)
```

Image I have two meetings, one starting at `8:30` and finishing at `12:00` and one starting at `14:00` and finishing at `16:00`, it would then return the following free slots :

- 12:00 - 13:00
- 12:15 - 13:15
- 12:30 - 13:30
- 12:45 - 13:45
- 13:00 - 14:00
- 16:00 - 17:00

I have no ideas how can I calculate these in a beautiful way. Trying each possibilities seems to be a bad plan and i wonder if there's a better way of doing it.